# Generating a Single Channel Mask

Tags: opencv, mask

Given a multichannel image (e.g. BGR), what's the most efficient way to generate a (binary) `1C` mask for pixel value equality?

`cv::compare()` works only for single channel input images.

Using `op==` yields a `3C` mask.
I can then `reduce` that but that seems like a wasteful second pass.

Is there a single pass way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For multi-channel Matrices, you need to use [`cv::inRange()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.8/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange), which takes single channel, 3 channel or 4 channel images as `src` and takes lower and upper bounds of the colors to be segmented. Since you want to test for equality of a given Color, you need to pass both `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` as the same Scalar value.

```
cv::Scalar color = cv::Scalar(100, 200, 150);
cv::Mat mask;
cv::inRange(img, color, color, mask);
```

Comment: Ah! I forgot about that function! Thanks!

Comment: For completeness, here a link from the latest docs: http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga48af0ab51e36436c5d04340e036ce981.